# onActivityResult getting RESULT_CANCELLED when using Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE

Tags: android, android-intent

I have the following button in my activity, that opens the gallery to select single or multiple images, and below this, the `OnActivityResult` function, that is returning result as `RESULT_CANCELLED` for multiple images, and `RESULT_OK` for a single image. Not sure why it's happening. Can someone please help.

```
buttonGallery.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), choose_picture);
    //startActivity(intent);
    }
});

//OnActivityResult for the above

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      if(requestCode == choose_picture) {
          Uri imageUri = (Uri)data.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
      //Do something
}
```

I'm getting `data.getData()` as `null`, `data.getExtras()` as `null`.

Can someone guide me how to get the required results from the above code. I want the `URIs` of all images that the user selects from the gallery.

PS : It's working fine for a single image, not sure why.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Finally I got the solution to this. When using `EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE`, when there is more than one content that the user is selecting, instead of being returned in `intent.getExtra()`, the data from the intent is returned in `ClipData`, which is only supported for SDK versions 18 and higher. From there, the data can be retrieved using the following code ->

```
 if ((Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) 
                                            && (null == data.getData())) 
 {
                ClipData clipdata = data.getClipData();
                for (int i=0; i<clipdata.getItemCount();i++)
                {
                    try {
                        Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), clipdata.getItemAt(i).getUri());
                        //DO something
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
}
```

I've put the null check for `intent.getData()` because in case of a single image, the data is received in `intent.getData()`, while in case of multiple selection, this is received as `null`.

So, for sdk versions below 18, and for single selection (irrespective of sdk version), the data can be simply retrieved in the following manner :

```
InputStream ist = this.getContentResolver()
                            .openInputStream(data.getData());
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ist);
```

Comment: I have data: Intent == null, how did you get it as not null to get clip data?