# KitKat ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT does not show documents on Samsung devices

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, samsung-touchwiz, storage-access-framework

I'm using the new Kitkat Storage Access Framework (SAF) as specified here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

This is the same as the example code but the images filter is not working. Nothing shows up on the S5 or the Note3. The same happens for video (video/*). I also tried different patterns like */* to not avail.

This looks like a Samsung issue that should be addressed by them, I'm just wondering if anyone knows a workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same on my Galaxy S4, and the only workaround I found was to reuse the old way:

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent();    
photoPickerIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 0);
```

But I suppose you first want to be sure to be on the specific device, since it works well with the Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT on other devices ... (I tried on Wiko Cink Slim and Nexus 5, with Android 4.4.2).

Hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks for that. This is also the "workaround" I'm resorting to right now but the issue is that multi-selection is not possible with the old way. I'll mark this as the answer if nobody comes up with something better.

Answer (score 9):

I was facing the same issue on samsung galaxy s4. During my research i figured out that the galaxy s4 was not supporting the Media document provider. Solved it by querying the media provider interface. This is what i did:

```
private void launchGallery()
{
    final Intent intent = new Intent();
    // Api 19 and above should access the Storage Access Framework
    if ( isMediaProviderPresent())
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    else
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    // Multi Picking is supported on api 18 and above.
    if (isApi18Above())
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);

    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"chooser"),
        RESULT_PHOTO_FROM_GALLERY);
}


private boolean isMediaProviderSupported()
{
    if(isApi19Above())
    {
        final PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();
        // Pick up provider with action string
        final Intent i = new Intent(DocumentsContract.PROVIDER_INTERFACE);
        final List<ResolveInfo> providers = pm.queryIntentContentProviders(i, 0);
        for (ResolveInfo info : providers)
        {
            if(info != null && info.providerInfo != null)
            {
                final String authority = info.providerInfo.authority;
                if(isMediaDocumentProvider(Uri.parse("content://"+authority)))
                    return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

  private static boolean isMediaDocumentProvider(final Uri uri)
    {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't think "Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE" works when using the old action, does it?

Comment: @frapim It works on Google+ photos, but not in other clients.

Comment: Also, if you like this answer can you please upvote ?

Comment: Would if I could, not enough reputation, sorry.

Comment: This helped me to process the response in case of multiple pictures. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24445002/1773155