# How to select multiple images from gallery and display them in a single activity using android code?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am using the following code to select the image from gallery and display them into a single activity (the layout need to consists with six images). What could I make the changes in the following code?

XML code activity_second_3.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    tools:context=".Second_Activity3">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_show_uploads"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Upload Products Images"
        android:textColor="#f00fff"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_choose_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/text_view_show_uploads"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="Choose file" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="231dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/text_view_show_uploads"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button_choose_image"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_choose_image" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view1"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_below="@id/spinner2"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="210dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="210dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="331dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view2"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_below="@id/spinner2"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="172dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="210dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="210dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="168dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view3"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_below="@id/spinner2"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="335dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="210dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="210dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view4"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_below="@id/spinner2"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="331dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view5"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_below="@id/spinner2"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="172dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="168dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view6"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_below="@id/spinner2"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="335dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button_upload"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_upload"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Upload" />   

</RelativeLayout>
```

Second_Activity3.java:

```
package com.example.project1;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.List;

public class Second_Activity3 extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    Button mButtonChooseImage;
    List <String> list_of_products;
    Spinner spino;
    ImageView mImageView1;
    ImageView mImageView2;
    ImageView mImageView3;
    ImageView mImageView4;
    ImageView mImageView5;
    ImageView mImageView6;
    ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    Uri mImageUri;
    Button mButtonUpload;
    StorageReference mStorageRef;
    DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second_3);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        mButtonChooseImage = findViewById(R.id.button_choose_image);
        mButtonChooseImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openFileChooser();
            }
        });
        mImageView1 = findViewById(R.id.image_view1);
        mImageView2 = findViewById(R.id.image_view2);
        mImageView3 = findViewById(R.id.image_view3);
        mImageView4 = findViewById(R.id.image_view4);
        mImageView5 = findViewById(R.id.image_view5);
        mImageView6 = findViewById(R.id.image_view6);

        mButtonUpload = findViewById(R.id.button_upload);
        mProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("products");
        mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("products");
    }    // Performing action when ItemSelected     // from spinner, Overriding onItemSelected method
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {        // On selecting a spinner item
        String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();        // Showing selected spinner item
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
    private void openFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        List<Uri> uris = null;
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            ClipData clipdata = data.getClipData();
            for (int i=0; i<clipdata.getItemCount();i++)
            {
                uris.add(clipdata.getItemAt(i).getUri());
            }
//            mImageUri = data.getData();
            Picasso.with(this).load(uris.get(0)).into(mImageView1);
            Picasso.with(this).load(uris.get(1)).into(mImageView2);
            Picasso.with(this).load(uris.get(2)).into(mImageView3);
            Picasso.with(this).load(uris.get(3)).into(mImageView4);
            Picasso.with(this).load(uris.get(4)).into(mImageView5);
            Picasso.with(this).load(uris.get(5)).into(mImageView6);

        }


    }
}
```

Currently, the above code is able to select multiple images since I used intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true); line in android code. Here, only six images need to select.

How could I select and display multiple images?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24445002/1105277

Comment: Does this answer your question? [onActivityResult getting RESULT\_CANCELLED when using Intent.EXTRA\_ALLOW\_MULTIPLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24433649/onactivityresult-getting-result-cancelled-when-using-intent-extra-allow-multiple)

Comment: according to your suggetion, I changed the code but I am not getting the result as required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am very thankful to you that you suggested me to get multiple Uri of selected images.

The uris object was not created it was just declared in the above code as:

```
uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
```

I didn't understand what was the exact problem but the following code able to fulfil my requirement:

```
package com.example.project1;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Second_Activity3 extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    Button mButtonChooseImage;
    List <String> list_of_products;
    Spinner spino;
    ImageView mImageView1;
    ImageView mImageView2;
    ImageView mImageView3;
    ImageView mImageView4;
    ImageView mImageView5;
    ImageView mImageView6;
    ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    Uri mImageUri;
    List<Uri> uris = null;
    Button mButtonUpload;
    StorageReference mStorageRef;
    DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second_3);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        mButtonChooseImage = findViewById(R.id.button_choose_image);
        mButtonChooseImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openFileChooser();
            }
        });

        uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();

        mImageView1 = findViewById(R.id.image_view1);
        mImageView2 = findViewById(R.id.image_view2);
        mImageView3 = findViewById(R.id.image_view3);
        mImageView4 = findViewById(R.id.image_view4);
        mImageView5 = findViewById(R.id.image_view5);
        mImageView6 = findViewById(R.id.image_view6);

        mButtonUpload = findViewById(R.id.button_upload);
        mProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("products");
        mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("products");
    }    // Performing action when ItemSelected     // from spinner, Overriding onItemSelected method
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {        // On selecting a spinner item
        String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();        // Showing selected spinner item
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
//    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
    private void openFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

//        if (data.getClipData() != null) {
            ClipData clipdata = data.getClipData();
            for (int i=0; i<clipdata.getItemCount();i++)
            {
                uris.add(clipdata.getItemAt(i).getUri());
                System.out.println("URL: "+clipdata.getItemAt(i).getUri());
            }
//            mImageUri = data.getData();
            Picasso.with(this).load(uris.get(0)).into(mImageView1);
            Picasso.with(this).load(uris.get(1)).into(mImageView2);
            Picasso.with(this).load(uris.get(2)).into(mImageView3);
            Picasso.with(this).load(uris.get(3)).into(mImageView4);
            Picasso.with(this).load(uris.get(4)).into(mImageView5);
            Picasso.with(this).load(uris.get(5)).into(mImageView6);

//        }


    }
}
```